# Attempting to call a method from another method within a class, getting a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

So, I have two methods here for adding/updating a card on a Trello board.  They are both declared in a class, with the updateWatchlistCard being declared before the second method addWatchlistCard.  I am getting the following error in my code when I make a call to the updateWatchlistCard in addWatchlistCard: TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here or why it is doing this.  I've tried rearranging the code, rewriting the function, and none of it has worked.

````
async updateWatchlistCard([cardData], card){

       console.log('fired updatewatchlistcard');
       //* Attempt to grab user data.
       try{
           var userId = await noblox.getIdFromUsername(cardData.Username);
           var properUsername = await noblox.getUsernameFromId(userId);
       }catch(error){
           return false;
       }

       //* Adds the check to the card.
       await Trello.addCommentToCard(card.id, 
          `**Moderator:** ${cardData.ModeratorName}:${cardData.ModeratorId}` +
          `\n**Suspicion:** ${cardData.Suspiscion}` +
          `\n**Evidence:** ${cardData.Evidence}` + 
          `\n**Comments:** ${cardData.Comments}`
       );

       return {value: '**Card updated successfully!**', cardName: card.name, cardUrl: card.url};
   }```

  ``` async addWatchlistCard([cardData]){

       // First search and see if the card already exists.
       var cardExists = await this.getModerationCard(cardData.Username, cardData.WatchlistId, cardData.BoardId);

       if(!cardExists){   
           //Tries getting new data for the card.
           try{
               var userId = await noblox.getIdFromUsername(cardData.Username);
               var properUsername = await noblox.getUsernameFromId(Number(userId));
           }catch(error){
               return false;
           }
           // Data for card fields.
           var cardTitle = (`${properUsername}:${userId}`);
           var cardDesc = (`Moderator: ${cardData.ModeratorName}:${cardData.ModeratorId}` + `\nSuspected of: ${cardData.Suspicion}` + `\nEvidence: ${cardData.Evidence}` + `\nComments: ${cardData.Comments}`);

           // Create the new card.
           var newCard = await Trello.addCard(cardTitle, cardDesc, cardData.WatchlistId);

           return {value: '**Card created successfully**', cardName: newCard.name, cardUrl: newCard.url};

       }else{
           console.log('got here.');
           let response = this.updateWatchlistCard(cardData, cardExists);
           return response;
       }
   } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  I figured out it had to do with the way I was writing the parameters in the updateWatchlistCard method.  Thanks!